# How to pack PHP files into exe?

Tags: php, exe

I just found out Luminotes (http://luminotes.com/) offers desktop version. I downloaded it and executed. When I execute it, Luminotes opens up a web-browser. It seems like that it uses its own internal webserver because URL shows http://localhost:6520/something@@#$

Is there a way to pack web language files into exe like Luminotes does?

Answer (score 1):

I found these programs to wrap a PHP web application into an exe :

http://www.zzee.com/phpexe/

http://www.exeoutput.com/index.php

Especially the last one looks great, but some changes to the application are required (for example : resources should be put into a Data directory). The documentation is great though.